# Architecture for multidimensional search from among billions of records

Tags: database, database-design

Our data consist of about 5 billions of records and will extend in future at least 1 billion per year. The most basic object is an offer (products sales). Each offer has a set of data after which you can search for it. Like:

- offer title (full text search),
- seller
- product category,
- price,
- start/end date
- transactions with date of sale, comments

etc. At least 10 dimensions and 2 of it need full text search. Not all of these are initially searchable but at least offer title, category, date of issue, seller are. Now out infrastructure is one strong server (40 cores, 256 GB RAM, bunch of SSDs) and these multidimensional, full search queries are supported by Elastic index. And now queries are bit too slow for WWW (average close to 10 sec.)

A basic question is what can be done to improve performance of such queries? The more detailed question divides to many "subquestions":

- what engines/technologies use
- how data replication across multiple servers affects performance
- can such queries be divided into "subproblems" and if so, how?

Our scenery is unfortunately a lack of money for heavily inflated infrastructure. Now we have 2 servers for downloading and processing data and one for WWW app. We can afford at least 2 servers for WWW. So answers like - "you want to improve performance 10 times - replicate your data on 20 other servers" are useless.

Comment: Data warehouses are not able to respond in less than a second.  You're lucky you're getting a 10 second response time.  Generally, your web site should work like a batch job, the user submits the query and gets a response 10 or 100 seconds later.

Comment: Well we generate some statistic reports for clients which take even much more than 100 seconds but this is acceptable. But WWW search engine with response of 100 sec? Google something and wait for answer 2 minutes. Disappointed? For sure :-)